# App getting crashed while using dictation in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, xcode6.1, uitextinput, dictation

The app is getting crashed while using dictation in UITextView .
While using dictation feature in keyboard the text is getting auto saved and the application getting crashed due to the same reason. 
Normal Scenario:

While user uses keyboard to enter the text through dictation mode, the text will be auto saved after 2 seconds.

Current scenario

While user try long speech texts through dictation mode , the text is getting autosaved and meanwhile the application itself is getting crashed.

Please find the stack trace

```html
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x371bbdfc
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'We were never set up properly to stream in this document.'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x294205f7 __exceptionPreprocess + 127
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x36b5ac77 objc_exception_throw + 36
2   CoreFoundation                       0x294204cd +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 102
3   Foundation                           0x2a0f4a49 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 90
4   UIKit                                0x2ce48c2b -[UIDictationStreamingOperations willEndEditingInInputDelegate:] + 136
5   UIKit                                0x2c8ecf4f +[UIDictationController keyboardWillChangeFromDelegate:toDelegate:] + 140
6   UIKit                                0x2c8ec717 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 320
7   UIKit                                0x2c8e64d1 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 1118
8   UIKit                                0x2c9b8631 -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 158
9   UIKit                                0x2c9634f5 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 274
10  UIKit                                0x2c96327f -[UITextView resignFirstResponder] + 76
11  Classroom                            0x00372f2f -[ComposerViewController autoSaveDraft] (ComposerViewController.m:1800)
12  Foundation                           0x2a1349e5 __NSFireTimer + 62
13  CoreFoundation                       0x293e6f07 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
14  CoreFoundation                       0x293e6a89 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 654
15  CoreFoundation                       0x293e4cf3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1416
16  CoreFoundation                       0x29331b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 474
17  CoreFoundation                       0x29331943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
18  GraphicsServices                     0x306e8051 GSEventRunModal + 134
19  UIKit                                0x2c923f21 UIApplicationMain + 1438
20  Classroom                            0x000e7493 main (main.m:13)
21  libdyld.dylib                        0x370f6aaf start + 0
```

Comment: Provide more details on scenario of issue

Comment: Updated the whole scenario

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20998592/849486)

Comment: i am also having similar issue with UIDictationController check this:-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405172/app-crashes-uitextview-when-user-inputs-via-voice?noredirect=1#comment75810926_44405172