# App Crashes uitextview when user inputs via voice

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uitextview, voice

App crashes when user inputs text via voice in UITextView,

**Crash Method**

***make textview first responder by clicking on it then Press on mic button in keyboard then speech something then press Done the app crashes..***

Nothing special is done with uitextview in my case..

**Console Output**

*

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable
>   object with deleteCharactersInRange:'

- > First throw call stack: (0x19443c1c0 0x192e7455c 0x19443c108
  >   0x1943d9b18 0x19a58d138 0x194e1a3c4 0x1943fd958 0x1943fb9e4
  >   0x194e1a218 0x19aa9aac8 0x19aa9b270 0x19aa9a0b4 0x19aa97680
  >   0x19aa979f0 0x19aa9afd0 0x19aa9b50c 0x19cdbf800 0x19cdbf064
  >   0x19cdbf74c 0x19cdc4354 0x1005e925c 0x1005e921c 0x1005ee284
  >   0x1943e9f2c 0x1943e7b18 0x194316048 0x195d99198 0x19a2e9628
  >   0x19a2e4360 0x1001e03c4 0x1932f85b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
  >   uncaught exception of type NSException

on further debugging i got (by entering bt in console) it gives me

> ```
> * thread #1: tid = 0x645a4, 0x000000019340a014 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue =
> ```
>
> 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
>           frame #0: 0x000000019340a014 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
>           frame #1: 0x00000001934d1460 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 112
>           frame #2: 0x000000019337e3f4 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 140
>           frame #3: 0x0000000192e492d4 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 132
>           frame #4: 0x0000000192e66cc0 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 304
>           frame #5: 0x0000000192e74844 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 124
>           frame #6: 0x0000000192e6366c libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
>           frame #7: 0x0000000192e62f84 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw + 136
>           frame #8: 0x0000000192e74690 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw + 364
>           frame #9: 0x000000019443c108 CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:] + 116
>           frame #10: 0x00000001943d9b18 CoreFoundation`mutateError + 132
>           frame #11: 0x000000019a58d138 UIKit`-[UIScrollView description] + 104
>           frame #12: 0x0000000194e1a3c4 Foundation`_NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 108
>           frame #13: 0x00000001943fd958 CoreFoundation`__CFStringAppendFormatCore + 7996
>           frame #14: 0x00000001943fb9e4 CoreFoundation`_CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 244
>           frame #15: 0x0000000194e1a218 Foundation`+[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 68
>           frame #16: 0x000000019aa9aac8 UIKit`-[UIDictationController insertSerializedDictationResult:withCorrectionIdentifier:] + 144
>           frame #17: 0x000000019aa9b270 UIKit`__98-[UIDictationController
>   finishDictationRecognitionWithPhrases:languageModel:correctionIdentifier:]_block_invoke
>   + 464
>           frame #18: 0x000000019aa9a0b4 UIKit`-[UIDictationController performIgnoringDocumentChanges:] + 48
>           frame #19: 0x000000019aa97680 UIKit`-[UIDictationController _runFinalizeOperation:] + 56
>           frame #20: 0x000000019aa979f0 UIKit`-[UIDictationController setState:] + 612
>           frame #21: 0x000000019aa9afd0 UIKit`-[UIDictationController finishDictationRecognitionWithPhrases:languageModel:correctionIdentifier:]
>   + 552
>           frame #22: 0x000000019aa9b50c UIKit`-[UIDictationController dictationConnection:didRecognizePhrases:languageModel:correctionIdentifier:]
>   + 204
>           frame #23: 0x000000019cdbf800 AssistantServices`__105-[AFDictationConnection
>   _tellSpeechDelegateDidRecognizeSpeechPhrases:languageModel:correctionIdentifier:]_block_invoke
>   + 80
>           frame #24: 0x000000019cdbf064 AssistantServices`-[AFDictationConnection
>   _dispatchCallbackGroupBlock:] + 240
>           frame #25: 0x000000019cdbf74c AssistantServices`-[AFDictationConnection
>   _tellSpeechDelegateDidRecognizeSpeechPhrases:languageModel:correctionIdentifier:]
>   + 356
>           frame #26: 0x000000019cdc4354 AssistantServices`__101-[AFDictationConnectionServiceDelegate
>   speechDidRecognizePhrases:usingSpeechModel:correctionContext:]_block_invoke
>   + 76
>           frame #27: 0x00000001005e925c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
>           frame #28: 0x00000001005e921c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
>           frame #29: 0x00000001005ee284 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1200
>           frame #30: 0x00000001943e9f2c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
>           frame #31: 0x00000001943e7b18 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1660
>           frame #32: 0x0000000194316048 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
>           frame #33: 0x0000000195d99198 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
>           frame #34: 0x000000019a2e9628 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 684
>           frame #35: 0x000000019a2e4360 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 208
>         * frame #36: 0x00000001001e03c4 motto-mobile`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fdd3ab8) + 124 at main.m:16
>           frame #37: 0x00000001932f85b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4

Code used

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) UITextView *addressTextView;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    addressTextView.delegate = self;
    addressTextView.text = [self.dictionaryEditObject objectForKey:@"location"];
}
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

}
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"textViewShouldBeginEditing:");

    return YES;
}

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"textViewDidEndEditing");
}
```

[image: By adding exception breakpoint it points me here only..]

tried on 
iOS: 10.2,9.3
device: iPad, iPod, iPhone 5s
crash on every device

Any Help Would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Add some code please, otherwise it's not clear how to point to your issue.

Comment: but there i can not see anything with code here...

Comment: is location value stirng? once format and check

Comment: yes it is, as it successfully added the text to textView...

Comment: Put the code where you use `deleteCharactersInRange`.

Comment: I have not used deleteCharactersInRange any where in this class neither its super class

Comment: clean your project and build then check and add voice receiving code

Comment: isn't the voice receiving code handled by os itself?

Comment: as there is no custom button for voice receiving, it's the keyboard's default voice input

Comment: then add exceptional break point check which line its crahsing

Comment: @karthikeyan already added exception breakpoint it doesnot give any line.., as i think it is due to internal issue...

Comment: You better search your app well for this deleteCharactersInRange method and make sure the place where you call it manually is not doing so on an object that is not able to handle this well. Place your breakpoint there.

Comment: deleteCharactersInRange is not used anywhere by me

Comment: Did you enable or decline any privacy setting?

Comment: is any privacy setting needed for voice input of uitextview?

Comment: just tried after adding "Privacy - Speech Recognition Usage Description" but nothing different happend

Comment: I am not sure..Check microphone usage description

Comment: tried this also, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to subclass UITextView and in that subclass override func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool. Then make a delegate that handles what happens when the TextView is activated and call it through the overridden method.

Then set the delegate of the TextView based on UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning(), so if voice over is running then set the UITextViewDelegate to nil which prevents the crash from happening and then the activation action is handled by the method you overrode in the subclass above. Finally, set up a listener for UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged and set the UITextViewDelegate to nil when going from off to on, and setting it to the original delegation class for the opposite scenario.

Comment: sorry didn't got you.., you are referring to which subclass?

Comment: I am referencing to subclassing UITextView